# What is the connection between different definitions for theta functions?

Tags: modular-forms, theta-functions

In his [2002 thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4834), Zwegers defines theta functions associated with definite and indefinite quadratic forms. For example, if $Q:\mathbb{R}^r\to \mathbb{R}$ is a positive definite quadratic form with associated bilinear form $B(x,y) = Q(x+y)-Q(x)-Q(y)$  then the theta series associated with $Q$ is

$$\Theta(z;\tau):=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^r}e^{2\pi i(Q(n)\tau+B(n,z))}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^r}q^{Q(n)+B(n,z)}.$$

$\Theta(0,\tau)$ is a modular form of weight $r/2$.

On the other hand, [Ono](https://bookstore.ams.org/cbms-102) defines theta functions in terms of Dirichlet characters, and cites a theorem of Serre and Stark that such theta functions form a basis for a space of weight 1/2 cusp forms. For example, if $\chi_0$ is the trivial character then

$$\theta_0(z)=\theta(\chi_0,0,z):=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}q^{n^2} = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{2\pi in^2z}.$$

Is there a connection between the quadratic form definition and the Dirichlet character definition for theta functions? Is there, for example, a sort of dictionary which allows you to pass from the Dirichlet definition for a theta function to the quadratic form definition?

Edit: The definition Ono gives for a theta function $\theta$ in terms of a Dirichlet character $\psi$ is the following:

1. If $\psi$ is even, then $\theta(\psi,0,z):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\psi(n)q^{n^2}.$
2. If $\psi$ is odd, then $\theta(\psi,1,z):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\psi(n)nq^{n^2}.$

Comment: I should add that I'm not sure every theta function defined in terms of, say, a Dirichlet character can also be defined in terms of an associated quadratic form. Answering this question would probably answer the one I posted above.

Comment: The definition in terms of quadratic forms is mostly standard. Please tell us what the definition in term of Dirichlet characters is so we can compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theta function attached to the trivial character is the theta function attached to the one dimensional lattice $\Bbb Z$ equipped with the usual quadratic form $q(z) = z^2$.

These are, of course, modular forms of half integral weight, which are automorphic forms on the metaplectic group.

To avoid this complication, a simpler example is to look at an imaginary quadratic field $K$ and an order $\mathcal O \subseteq K$, e.g. the ring of integers of $K$.

We can then attach to any ideal of $\mathcal O$ a theta function, which is given by viewing the ideal as a lattice, equipped with the quadratic form $N_{K/\Bbb Q}$.

If $\chi$ is any ring class character of order $\mathcal O$, then the theta series attached to $\chi$ is in fact a finite linear combination of the various theta series attached to the ideals (one for each ideal class).

Conversely, any theta function attached to a lattice can also be written as a linear combination of theta series attached to characters.

---

If you are interested in a more general setting of theta series (for $\operatorname{GL}_2$), then you should have a look at [the Weil representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_group#Construction_of_the_Weil_representation). All the local Weil representations pack together to an adelic Weil representation, which then automatically gives rise to theta functions.